# Как правильно использовать метод Include() в паттерне Repository?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, linq2sql

При построении приложения использую паттерн Repository.
Интерфейс репозитория:

```
public interface IShopContext
{
    IQueryable<T> GetAllIncluding<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] include) where T : class;
}
```

Реализация интерфейса в контексте EF:

```
public class ShopContext : DbContext, IShopContext
{
    public ShopContext()
        : base("name=ShopDB")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Customer>    Customers { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Order>      Orders { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<T> GetAllIncluding<T>(params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] include) where T : class
    {
        var retVal = this.Set<T>();

        foreach(var item in include)
        {
            retVal.Include(item);
        }

        return retVal;

    }
}
```

Использую подход CodeFirst. База сгенерирована. В SQL SMS 2014 связь между таблицами Customers-Orders : One-to-Many и видна на диаграме. Данные в таблице присутствуют.

```
Классы сущностей:

public class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Patronymic { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public Customer()
    {
        Orders = new List<Order>();
    }
}

public class Order
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Тестовый код

```
[TestInitialize]
void Initialize()
{
    con = new ShopContext();            
}

[TestMethod]
public void Query_GetCustomersListIncluding_NoExc()
{
    Initialize();

    var l = con.GetAllIncluding<Customer>(c => c.Orders).ToList();

    foreach (var item in l)
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation($"{item.LastName}");
        foreach (var i in item.Orders)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation($"{i.Number}");
        }                
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что этот тест выдаёт в output только фамилии customer'ов, но не выводит заказы. При дебаге обнаружил, что переменные которые должны содержать в себе ссылку на объект с коллекцией заказов, пустые. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка тут:

```
retVal.Include(item);
```

Должно быть:

```
retVal = retVal.Include(item);
```